Bluetooth "stuttering" Inspiron 15 3520
I've been using Ubuntu for quite a while now and I solved some bugs here and there, but recently my bluetooth buds (Redmi buds 3 pro) are kinda "stuttering", this problem began when I updated my notebook (Dell Inspiron 15 3520) from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (now Im using 24.10 and it's still doing it), I've tried changing the codec, I've tried reinstalling the bluetooth drivers, I've tried reading the journalctl but tbh I didn't understand much about it and the last time I tried fixing it using ChatGPT I accidentally uninstalled "Apparmor" and got rid of all my snaps... It's getting kinda annoying now and I don't really know what to do anymore...
PS.: Sorry for bad english, it's not my "mother language" and I haven't talked in english in a while lol.
PS2.: The problem doesn't seem to be on the buds, cuz Im using it normally on my cellphone and it doesn't stutter.
